# "was" or "were"? -- "Several thousand pounds' worth of jewellery ____ discovered in his pocket."

Tags: grammar, conjugations

Which one is the correct version of "was" here: singular or plural?

Can *were* be replaced with *was* in the following sentence?

> Several thousand pounds' worth of jewellery *were* discovered in his pocket.

Answer (score 1):

Both are found. I first thought *was* is more natural, but I've changed my mind: *were* is more likely.

On the surface, the logical subject is *Several thousand pounds worth*, which is uncountable; but in practice, that phrase usually acts as a quantifier, so the effective subject is *jewellery*, which is uncountable; so either way, the verb should be singular *was*.

However, in cases like these, there are other considerations.

First, a plural noun somewhere in the phrase (such as *several thousand pounds*) can influence things, leading to *were*. (This effect is even stronger if the plural noun is closer to the verb, but that is not the case here).

Finally, even though *jewellery* is uncountable, we are usually aware that it may consist of a number of separate objects. When there isn't an apparently plural quantifier this has no effect (*Some jewellery was found*, not *were found*), but with the *several thousand pounds* influencing it as well, I think *were* is more likely.

**Edited** to change my view of which is more likely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you mean in the above-mentioned sentence using either "was" or "were" would be equally correct? Or "were" is more likely to be used than "was"?

Comment: I mean that people say it with either _was_ or _were_; and after some thought I believe that _were_ is more common.

Comment: *Several thousand pounds' worth* is both the logical and effective subject. *Of jewellery* is clearly a qualifier specifying the type of *worth*; the sentence is meaningful without it. Semantically we know that it's jewellery that was discovered, but the focus of the sentence is on the *worth*. This sentence tells us ***how much** jewellery was discovered*.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: I disagree. Without a context establishing that the subject was jewellery, _several thousand pounds' worth was found._ is no more meaningful than _twenty kilos were found_.

Comment: But *twenty kilos were found* is meaningful. Say this in the US and it'll be understood that you're talking about narcotics. Your assumption that the context must only come from within the sentence is overly simplistic at best.

Comment: I didn't say that the context must only come from within the sentence. I said "without a context": I was thinking of that context being established by the previous discourse, but it can certainly be established by social or physical context.

Comment: Fair enough, some sort of context is required. The adjectival phrase *of jewellery* provides it here, but that does not cause *jewellery* to be the subject of the sentence, especially given the grammatical construction. My point is that the focus is clearly on the value, not the type. The *worth* is the important bit and the subject. The sentence is qualifying the worth, not quantifying the jewellery. *Jewellery worth several thousand pounds* is the typical way to do what you're suggesting. Most importantly, it's bad advice to tell *learners* to conjugate based on the object of a preposition.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: I think we'll just have to agree to disagree. I agree that _several thousand pounds worth_ can be analysed as the subject, but I maintain that it can also be analysed as a quantifier, with _jewellery_ as the subject.